# Entitiy does not get load from fixtures data

Tags: java, playframework, yaml, playframework-1.x, fixtures

What is wrong with the following YAML code? All the entities get loaded in the database, except the PinBoard, which is sort of an intermediary entity Board and Pin. What am I doing wrong there?

```
Board(board1):
    name: Board1
    urlFormattedName: travel
Pin(pin1):
    name: Pin1
    catId: 12345
Pin(pin2):
    name: Pin2
    catId: 23456    
PinBoard:
    board: board1
    pin: pin1
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are relating objects you need to use [ ] so it should be:

```
PinBoard:
board: [board1]
pin: [pin1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
PinBoard(pinBoard1):
    board: board1
    pin: pin1
```

also check that `not null` properties of modals **must** be set